# How to execute requests from backend deamon for graph.microsoft.com API endpoints that do not support application permissions?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

It is more about how microsoft cloud API and azure application implementation details...

I would like to set up the backend deamon that would periodically get data from microsoft's online Office 365 Excel documents, and store it to database.

I've successfully went with authorisation part, for so called "client credentials flow" (RFC6749 describes it as "client credentials grant").

So I authenticate and get a valid token, without need for a user to interact. It goes with azure application that I set up on https://portal.azure.com, and that has permissions confirmed by admin. Now I'm able to execute requests to https://graph.microsoft.com like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/drives
```

The problem is that does not solve requests that assumes calls with authenticated user and not application like below does not work:

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ/workbook/worksheets('test')/usedRange"
```